# Overflow visible of <div> in <td> with another <div> in next <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I need to create a table with `table-layout: fixed` that contains in a first `<td>` a `<div>` with `overflow: visibile` and in the next `<td>` another `<div>` that go to head in the `<tr>` insted of stay below. 
The result I would like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/odGqs.png

The `<tr>` should double the height and the red box go down.
This is my code:

```css
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 350px;
}

th, td, thead, tbody{
    border: 1px black solid;
}

th, td{
    width: 40px;
}

.div1{
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: brown;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.div2{
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="content"><div class="div1"></div></div></td>
            <td><div class="content"><div class="div2"></div></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>loremlorem</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you to everyone!

Comment: Hi, there's a bit I don't quite understand - you say the red box should go down. Should that be the blue box (which corresponds to the picture)?

Comment: Of course, sorry, I meant the blue box!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in many ways. One of the method is `position: absolute` and adjust `top` value in css and also adjust `height` attribute in `<tr>` according to your need.

```css
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 350px;
}

th, td, thead, tbody{
    border: 1px black solid;
}

th, td{
    width: 40px;
}

.div1{
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: brown;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.div2{
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr height=150>
            <td><div class="content"><div class="div1"></div></div></td>
            <td><div class="content"><div class="div2"></div></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>loremlorem</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: According to [link]developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes  height is a legacy attribute.on some tags (which includes tr).